# How to set status code 404 instead of 200 for 404-page in Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, next.js

I have inquired about the way of setting 404 status code to 404-page in Next.js but the response I was given was that this is not true, that the status code is 404 by default. I was not able to present print screens in the comment, so I want to present them here, and possibly get the answer I am after.
Truth is that all the bad requests have status code of 404, but the 404-page itself has status 200[image]
as you can see, the first two positions are with status code 200. I want to trigger 404 every time the url does not match a page in my pages directory, but to be returned with status code 404 instead of 200. Or if this is possible I would prefer to have it redirected with status code 301 to page 404, and the url after redirect to be eg. /404?url=%2Fbadrequest.
Would you please at least point me in the direction. I don't know whether it should be done client or server side. I imagine I need to react server side to set the proper response code, but how? And to redirect and build up an url like /404?url=%2Fbadrequest does it have to be done client or server side?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two requests you are referring to are script and fetch/XHR requests not the page (see ***Type***, it will be `document` for pages; alternatively you can select "Doc" in filters). The page (`/badrequest`) is requested in the last request in your image (and responded with `404` status code). Those JS files are just used to render the `404` error component.

For the redirect part you can do something like this:

```js
// pages/[...slug.js]

const Fake = () => <></>;
export default Fake;

const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: `/404?url=${encodeURI(req.url)}`,
      permanent: true
    }
  };
};

export { getServerSideProps };
```

```js
// pages/404.js

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ErrorPage = () => {
  const { asPath: path } = useRouter();
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPath(
      decodeURI(
        new URLSearchParams(path.replace(/^.*?\?/, "")).get("url") || ""
      )
    );
  }, [path]);

  return <div>{currentPath} Not Found</div>;
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Code Sandbox: [codesandbox.io/s/bitter-glade-btrcp](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-glade-btrcp)

---

PS: Status code `308` means "Permanent Redirect"

If you want `301` status code, then change `pages/[...slug.js]` to this:

```js
const Fake = () => <></>;
export default Fake;

const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  res.writeHead(301, { location: `/404?url=${encodeURI(req.url)}` }).end();
  return { props: {} };
};

export { getServerSideProps };
```

I've updated the sandbox accordingly.

Comment: wow is not enough, thanks a million @brc-dd! So actually did not have a problem, just could not read Network tab properly ;p But the most awesome stuff is that i have access to req and res obj in getStaticProps in Docs i saw there is a context prop but when i logged it there were only locales. Thank you very much, you helped me a ton!

Comment: @Seven You don't have access of `req`/`res` in `getStaticProps` as it is executed during build. However you do have access of them in `getServerSideProps`. [Refer docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering).

Comment: right, I get it now, and again, thank you very much for your time. Your answer helped me to understand more about Next's data flow

Comment: Hi @brc-dd it turned out we have a static hosting and cannot use getServerSideProps I'm trying to come up with a similar solution but getStaticProps does not have access to {req,res}, and it is required to have getStaticPaths together with getStaticProps if you have dynamic route like this [...fake] and if you send nothing via paths, it will react to nothing instead of everything ;p I cannot think of a solution to cover all invalid routes this way, I've been thinking of setting fallback to true and redirect it via router on every single page but it seems tedious, and Next should handle that

Comment: @Seven What exactly do you mean by "static hosting"? Are you doing static HTML export in Next.js? Because if you are thinking of setting `fallback: true` in `getStaticPaths`, it does server-side rendering for the first time a route is being requested. You can't do it on a hosting where you can't use `getServerSideProps`. If you are statically exporting HTML, then you need to configure your server (nginx or whatever you are using) to handle this. The status code can't be send from within the client code.

Comment: Hi @brc-dd thanks a lot, I think this is what we have, I'm not yet full stack just front end, so my understanding is limited, but we use only getStaticProps and Paths and i can't use getServerSideProps so i assume this is the case. Its a bit of relief as i was feeling stupid not being able to accomplish this task successfully :) I just would like to clarify one more thing, the status code cant be sent, thats ok, but about this redirecting if in Network tab the site that generates the error is a document with 404 and in the url there is name of this website and 404 is being displayed

Comment: That would mean that neither 404 hit was recorded by google nor the non-existing site that generated the error and SEO will not be affected?

Comment: I guess yes. Error pages are not indexed by Google. Also its crawler can identify when a served page is an error page even if 404 status is not sent. Moreover, just provide Google a sitemap and before deploying check that your page has no broken links.